# pyinstaller .exe taskbar icon works properly only after pinning it to start

Tags: pyinstaller, exe

I coverted my .py file to .exe using the pyinstaller, when  the start the application the default taskbar icon is dispaly. But when i click on pin to start the set icon is shown properly and has no issue. But why do i need to pin to start initially.

I have used this command for converting

```
pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon UT_logo2.ico --add-data="UT_logo2.ico;." em_modbus_conf_utility_v1_0.py -w
```

My issue is when i share the exe to other user the need to pin to start as well. How to solve this.